# How can I exit the loading screen early?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

[image]

As seen here, sometimes when I'm loading a map, especially on Community Quickplay, I sometimes want to opt out.  Is there a certain way I can quickly exit this screen back to the menu?

I've tried pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, but that doesn't seem to do anything. I can get the console to open, but I can't do anything except "exit", which closes the game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this command into the console to disconnect from the server:

`disconnect`

Or even better You could bind a key for this command in Your autoexec.cfg like this:

`bind q disconnect`